# How to make IE10 default run in IE8 mode every time?

Tags: internet-explorer

As title,
We can change the IE Mode after opening IE by F12 (developer mode)
but I want to run in IE8 mode every time without change it manually,
is there anyway, thanks

Comment: Is this for viewing a particular website or for viewing all websites ?

Comment: now I need it for viewing all websites!

Answer (score 7):

Go to the following path in your registry (run Registry Editor with the command `regedit.exe` from the Start Menu's `Run` command):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\
  Software\
    Microsoft\
      Internet Explorer\
        Main\
          FeatureControl\
            FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

Then...

1. Right-click on or in the folder and select `New`, then select `DWORD (32-bit) Value`.
2. Enter "iexplore.exe" (without quotes) for the Name and press `Enter`.
3. Double-click on the key (or press Enter). The Edit dialog opens.
4. Ensure the `Base` is set as `Decimal`.
5. Enter "9999" (without quotes) and click the `OK` button. Close Registry Editor.
6. Close all Internet Explorer windows.

IE will open by default as IE9.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough points to add a comment to skia.heliou's post, but if you wanted your browser to default to a different mode here's an article for setting the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION DWORD ([Internet Feature Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation)).

If you want it to always be in IE8 mode you would use `8888`.

Comment: I put `8888` and browse IE and browser mode comes out unknown NOT IE8.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about IE8 mode but I know you can set IE7 mode on at all times... 
Simply open up Internet Explorer and press ALT + T and then press B.
Here you can add sites you wish to always display in Compatibility View or even tick "Display all websites in Compatibility View".

You can verify it is set correctly by pressing F12 on the pages you've set to display in compatibility view.